# Positioning UL absolutely when parent is overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a 'mega nav' only I'm running into some issues when I use a custom scrollbar.

My issue is that the custom `scrollbar` adds markup adding overflow hidden to my `nav` and as a result the `.sub-nav` element becomes hidden.

The only solution I can think of is to add position fixed to the `.sub-nav` element and then position it using `JavaScript` which very messy and not that reliable.

I've pasted 2 fiddles showing what I mean - I hope these make sense and any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks

**Without Plugin**

http://jsfiddle.net/f4qh27n7/11/

**With Plugin**

http://jsfiddle.net/f4qh27n7/10/

**Function to position element**

```
function calcNav(){
if( $('#breadcrumb').length > 0 ){
    var b = $('#breadcrumb').offset().top;
    var w = $(window).scrollTop();
    var x = b - w;
    $('.sub-nav').css('top', x);
}

}
calcNav();

var scrollTimeout;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout( scrollTimeout );
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout( calcNav, 50 );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty similar to @Lajon solution.

Just needed a little bit of restructuring:
http://jsfiddle.net/8zxq5jas/4/

Kind of what you where looking for?

```
$(".js-parent-category")
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        var target = $(this).attr("data-sub-nav-target");
        var element = $("." + target);
        element.addClass("active");
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
        var target = $(this).attr("data-sub-nav-target");
        var element = $("." + target);
        element.removeClass("active");
    });

$(".demo").customScrollbar();
```

```
<ul class="products-nav btcf">
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Products Mega Nav -->
<div class="mega-nav btcf">

    <ul class="parent-cat demo gray-skin scrollable">
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-1">Parent Category 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-2">Parent Category 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-3">Parent Category 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-4">Parent Category 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-5">Parent Category 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-6">Parent Category 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-7">Parent Category 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-8">Parent Category 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-9">Parent Category 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="js-parent-category" data-sub-nav-target="js-sub-nav-10">Parent Category 10</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-1 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-2 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 2</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-3 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-4 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 4</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-5 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 5</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-6 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 6</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-7 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 7</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-8 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 8</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-9 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 9</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="js-sub-nav-10 sub-nav">
        <h3>Sub Category 10</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to move all your sub-nav's out of the demo parent.

I would change the DOM structure to something as:

```
<div class="mega-nav">
     <div class="sub-nav"></div>
     <div class="sub-nav"></div>
     <div class="sub-nav"></div>

     <ul class="parent-cat demo gray-skin">
          <li><a href="#">Parent Category</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parent Category</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parent Category</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

After changing the DOM structure to the one above you can use index() to target relevant content on hover:

```
 var tid;
 $('.sub-nav').hide();

 $('.products-nav').delegate(".parent-cat .viewport .overview > li", "mouseenter", function () {
      $('.sub-nav').hide();
      clearTimeout(tid);

      $($(".sub-nav")[$(this).index()]).show();
 });

 $('.products-nav').delegate(".parent-cat .viewport .overview > li", "mouseleave", function () {
     tid = setTimeout(function () {
           $('.sub-nav').hide();
     }, 1000);
  });

 $(".demo").customScrollbar();
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lajon/ohtwrttm/2/)

Comment: And show the relevant sub navigation on parent hover?

Comment: Yes, you would have to slightly change your script to show relevant content for each `$(".parent-cat li")` object on hover.